# On hover instead of 'click' header account links RWD theme magento 1.9.4

Tags: magento-1.9, rwd-theme

I'd like to use hover instead of click to display the head-account drop down links. I added the javascript to the bottom of header.phtml

> app\design\frontend\rwd\default\template\page\html\header.phtml

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $j(document).ready(function(){
        $j(".skip-account").hover(function() {
            $j(this).addClass("skip-active");
            $j("#header-account").addClass("skip-active");
        }, function() {
            $j(this).removeClass("skip-active");
            $j("#header-account").removeClass("skip-active");
        });
        $j(".skip-content").hover(function() {
            $j(this).addClass("skip-active");
            $j(".skip-account").addClass("skip-active");
        }, function() {
            $j(this).removeClass("skip-active");
            $j(".skip-account").removeClass("skip-active");
        });
    });
</script>
```

But when I hover the head search box, there is a shadow under the search box. Also when I hover the main menu, the background has a shadow. Please advise. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use `id` of this div 
`<div id="header-account" class="skip-content">...</div>`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $j(document).ready(function(){
        $j(".skip-account").hover(function() {
            $j(this).addClass("skip-active");
            $j("#header-account").addClass("skip-active");
        }, function() {
            $j(this).removeClass("skip-active");
            $j("#header-account").removeClass("skip-active");
        });
        $j("#header-account").hover(function() { // just this line
            $j(this).addClass("skip-active");
            $j(".skip-account").addClass("skip-active");
        }, function() {
            $j(this).removeClass("skip-active");
            $j(".skip-account").removeClass("skip-active");
        });
    });
</script>
```